# What is this problem on this succulent?

Tags: watering, succulents, cactus

I have this succulent in my indoor since last few months. I just moved it outside few days back and now they look like this.

[image]

This is how I ruined this plant :(

1. I moved it to sunlight which was all of a sudden.
2. Then the leaves looked burnt. So, I watered too.
3. I uprooted the plant today, the soil looks wet.

Currently, the leaves are dropping as you can see that in the pic. Color is also turning to reddish instead of green.

I am not sure if this is sunburn or over-watering.
How can I save this plant? Also, should I trim the empty branch at the top ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your plants have been indoors during the last few months, they needed to be hardened off before placing outside. That means acclimatising them gradually, especially in order to cope with much lower temperatures outdoors overnight, so its necessary to place the plant/s outdoors for a short period in the middle of the day, not in sun, for an hour or two, then bring them back in, and repeat this process for extending periods over a week or two, until, on a mild night, they are left out overnight and can then stay outdoors for the rest of the summer.

Given where you are in the world, its likely overnight temperatures were a real shock, and the plant may be damaged beyond repair. The only thing you can do is to return it inside and keep it there, don't overwater, and hope it recovers. The browning of the leaves may be due to sudden exposure to sunlight, or to cold, and is not related to shortage of water.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :).  Also, should I trim the top stem, because, the leaves have fallen anyway ?

Comment: If the stem is dead, yes, remove it carefully at the base where it joins the leaves